# How to prevent XSS attack while using window.location.toString()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting error in checkmarx for the code `windw.location.toString()` what is the best to prevent this error?

error:

> method at line 74 gets user input for the toString() element. the
>   elements value then flows thrugh client side code without being
>   properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the
>   user in line 80. this may enable t dom css attack.

Comment: Include the relevant code lines where the error occurs... And the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
encodeURIComponent(myUrl);
```

You can then parse it safely and when done do:

```
decodeURIComponent(myUrl);
```

Comment: var a = encodeURIComponent(window.location.toString());
a = decodeURIComponent(a); 
 hi @maninak , is it correct

Comment: Yup. Try printing it to see what encoding does to the string. Practically any embedded code is rendered inert while encoded.

Comment: @CharanTej If your question has been answered please mark it as such to close it.